# "No content provider execution " error while converting uri to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-emulator

i am trying to retrieve an image from the `Uri` , firstly i selected the image from gallery then passed the imagePath using an intent  and trying to get the image from `Uri` by using this codes -

```
        Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageUri"));


        Log.d("" + imgUri, " here it is");


        InputStream PIS;


            try {

                PIS = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);
                 mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(PIS);


            } catch (Exception e){

                Log.d("go home you're drunk "+e,"");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

            }
```

but  am getting this error

```
01-19 04:59:50.627 847-858/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=pb.imagepicker/.CropActivity (has extras)} from uid 10060 on display 0
01-19 04:59:50.668 6072-6072/? D//storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160118_124651.jpg:  here it is
01-19 04:59:50.668 6072-6072/? D/go home you're drunk java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0�di[ 01-19 04:59:50.769  6072: 6085 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

// some extra errors

```
 01-19 05:33:06.419 6565-6580/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe8e32360, error=EGL_SUCCESS
 01-19 05:33:06.564 6565-6580/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 01-19 05:33:06.564 6565-6580/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe8e328c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

you can see i have the `uri` on  my `imgUri` , don't know what am doing wrong or missing if anybody knows what am missing than please correct  me  thanks :)

am using genyMotion emulator is it the cause of  problem ?

Comment: did you read `openInputStream` documentation ?

Comment: @pskink no i just adopted it from a similar scenario

Comment: so do that and you will know what `Uri schema`s are supported

Comment: have no idea dude about that :( what it is ?

Comment: errrr, what is what? see [uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had faced the same problem , maybe its happening because of your emulator changing the emulator worked form me , i moved from genymotion to blueStack and it worked for don't know why it happened , you should give it a shot

http://www.bluestacks.com/download.html

Comment: thanks this its what i already tried :D and yeah it worked for me after eating my 3+ hours on genymotion's emulator

Answer (score 6):

Append this permissions into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
 <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and use

`Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://"+getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageUri"));`

Comment: hey brother firstly thanks for responding , i tried as you suggested but i didn't seems to work still getting the same output

Comment: I just had to add "file://" with my path variable.

Comment: The best is to use
Uri mUri=Uri.fromFile(new File(yourpath));